# SQL connectivity error from Azure virtual network and vnet peering

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

I have got the network configuration below, however when I attempt to connect to SQL I get the error below. That is SQL 2 on the diagram below. I can connect to SQL1 without any problems. The difference that I can see here is that SQL1 is on the same vnet as the virtual network gateway. Ideally I would prefer to split this and have a network peering in place as per the diagram. The peering is 2 way, to the main network and back to the test network. I am unsure as to what I have done incorrectly here.

Cannot connect to xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.windows.net.

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 11001)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the Azure logical server name should be in the following format: yourservername.database.windows.net. The name you shared with on your question has the following format xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.windows.net and omits the word database. That produces the error "No such host is known" independent of the networking configuration.

DNS resolution may be a factor when error "No such host is known" is received.